# Navigation Bar is missing when using Quick Actions

Tags: ios, swift

I am using quick actions for my app and they are working correctly, except that the Navigation Bar is missing (no back button). Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController

    switch shortcutItem.type {
    case "AddIncome":
        vc.type = .income
        app?.mainVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        app?.mainVC.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case "AddExpense":
        vc.type = .expense
        app?.mainVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        app?.mainVC.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

`mainVC` is actually the view controller from where I present the `AddViewController`, the vc where my navigation bar is missing.

I can't seem to see what the issue is. Do I have to do some additional stuff to make it work correctly ?

Comment: There wouldn't be a back button when you present a view controller modally.

Comment: @dan: you we're right. I was presenting them modally. just had to get the navigation controller and do a push. Please provide this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kobe You need to add a navigation controller to show navigation bar when you presenting any view controller. Just try below code.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddViewController") as! AddViewController
    var nav = UINavigationController()
    nav.viewControllers = [vc]
    switch shortcutItem.type {
    case "AddIncome":
        vc.type = .income
        app?.mainVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        app?.mainVC.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case "AddExpense":
        vc.type = .expense
        app?.mainVC.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        app?.mainVC.present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Now you can add back button on AddViewController.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style:.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.moveToPreviousScreen))
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = button
}
```

Hope it will help you thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of points you can consider:

1. Have you added a Navigation Controller. (I know its too basic but some forget)
2. Have you set your view controller as the root for the navigation controller?
3. You can try setting the navigation bar programmatically.